# How to deal with ad serving is limited and very low match rate on admob

Tags: admob, admob-rewardedvideoad, firebase-admob, cordova-admob

I have 15 app on play store and they have 100k daily active users and those apps include admob ads but the 'ad serving is limited' is applied on my account and match rate is less that 2%.
I barely make one dollar per day since they applied limits.
what should I do to solve it? or I should change admob to another ads platform?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.